# Add values to $_SESSION['name'] then Loop thru values

Tags: php, php-7

I'm using a $_SESSION variable to store error codes in an app I'm creating.
On my form processing page, i'm using the following code (as an example):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['site_msg']   = array();
if(1 == 1) {
    $_SESSION['site_msg'] = 18;
}
if(2 == 2) {
    $_SESSION['site_msg'] = 21;
}
if(3 == 3) {
    $_SESSION['site_msg'] = 20;
}
```

I'm hoping to use a function to get the values from the array to use elsewhere in my code.

```
function error_code() {
    foreach($_SESSION['site_msg'] as $value) {
        echo "Value: $value <br />";
    }
}
```

The above gives an error; Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...

If I write the function like this:

```
$array[] = $_SESSION['site_msg'];
foreach($array  as $value) {
echo  "VAL: " . $value;
}
```

It only gives me the last value, 20.

Anyone have an idea where I went wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the point to use `if(1 == 1)` ?

Comment: I'm just testing the coding.  Obviously, my final code will not contain 1 == 1.  That's why in my question, I indicate, "As an example".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['site_msg']   = array();
if(1 == 1) {
    array_push($_SESSION['site_msg'],18);   // '=' overwrites the data, so push data in session array not to assign
}
if(2 == 2) {
    array_push($_SESSION['site_msg'],21);
}
if(3 == 3) {
    array_push($_SESSION['site_msg'],20);
}


$array = $_SESSION['site_msg'];  //remove [] from variable, its not needed
foreach($array  as $value) {
    echo  "VAL: " . $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no need to declare a second array `$array`. He can directly use the `$_SESSION['site_msg']` in the forearch loop.

Answer (score 1):

You declare your variable `$_SESSION['site_msg']` as an array, but you pass integer values to this variable! You need to add your values as new array elements.

This should work:

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION['site_msg']   = array();
if(1 == 1) {
    $_SESSION['site_msg'][] = 18;
}
if(2 == 2) {
    $_SESSION['site_msg'][] = 21;
}
if(3 == 3) {
    $_SESSION['site_msg'][] = 20;
}
```

As an alternative you can use the function `array_push()` to add your values to the array:

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION['site_msg']   = array();
if(1 == 1) {
    array_push($_SESSION['site_msg'], 18);
}
if(2 == 2) {
    array_push($_SESSION['site_msg'], 21);
}
if(3 == 3) {
    array_push($_SESSION['site_msg'], 20);
}
```